# Getting error 403 while accessing role based end points using jdbc authentication and bcrypt with spring security 6.2 and spring boot 3.2 and JDK 17

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have made some rest end points.i have enabled role based authentication and authorization.but the problem is the rest end point i am making public is doing well ,but the end points i have made to authenticate and authorize are not working .It is throwing error 403.i am hitting request in browser.I have define two roles user and admin.I have made two tables users and authorities in database and connected with foreign key with coulmn username.

**I have one more doubt ,i am using custom filter chain with my own user name and password and as per my knowledge ,the default token should not be generated in my console which is still being generated.Please have a look at  that also . i am attaching screen shot.**

Please help .i have been stuck in this issue from last 20 days.tried everything.but still facing error 403.

Here is my Security Config Class

```
package com.telusko.securityconfiguration;

import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestBuilders.formLogin;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigApp {
    
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    
    @Autowired
    public void authenticationManager(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        
        auth
        .jdbcAuthentication()
        .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password,enabled from users where username=?")
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username,authority from authorities where username=?"); 
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain customFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.cors(cors->cors.disable())
        .authorizeHttpRequests(
        request ->request.requestMatchers("/api/").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers("/api/admin/").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .requestMatchers("/api/user/").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        ).httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
        .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
        }
}
```

Here is my Controller Class

```
package com.telusko.restcontroller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserRestController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String welcome() {
        return "<h1>Welcome to Ineuron Family</h1>";
    }
    @GetMapping("/admin")
    public String adminProcess() {
        return "<h1>Welcome admin</h1>";
    }
    @GetMapping("/user")
    public String userProcess() {
        return "<h1>Welcome user</h1>";
    }
}
```

here is my application properties file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/oct_batch1
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=Lumia@541

logging.level.org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder=INFO
```

here is my

```
package com.telusko;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication()
@ComponentScan()
public class SpringSecurityJdbcAuthenticationApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringSecurityJdbcAuthenticationApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Here is the error i am recieving

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Jan 16 10:23:55 IST 2024
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
Forbidden
```

[[[[[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSmOX.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyWOw.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyd9d.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaBTI.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFDvw.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/od7Z3.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrMCn.png)

i have tried lambada dsl as i am using spring security 6.2 and cors disable ,chatgpt,bing ai but still it is not working.

Comment: this should be fixed in Java 21

Comment: @PerdiEstaquel can u please explain in more detail.

Comment: Hi, you could enable spring security debug logging for example with spring boot: logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG

Comment: @RabihSarieddine enabled the logger. But unable to understand it.

Comment: You need to delete the `@ComponentScan`

Comment: @Toerktumlare I have done that. It is not working

Comment: on your image the logs show that the default password is being printed. This means that the default spring security configuration is still in place and that your `SecurityConfigApp` is not loaded, why that is so i cant tell, but thats what you should investigate.

Comment: like why do you have an `@Autowired` annotation on the `public void authenticationManager(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` should be a `@Bean` annotation

Comment: I would put /api/admin/* and /api/user/* in the request matchers

Comment: It's quite funny that this question concerning an issue with Spring Security 6.2  is closed because it is duplicated with another one answered 6-7 years ago! Well, this post of mine: https://medium.com/@zzpzaf.se/spring-boot-just-4-beans-for-implementing-a-default-jdbc-authentication-with-d6fc052da48d, I think will be quite helpful.